# Ruby on Rails Multiple Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a three tables Plan, Channel and ChannelCategory. While creating a new Plan I want to select multiple channel_categories and based on that I want to select multiple channels. Please provide me the solution.

Comment: Can you please post your code ?

Answer (score 1):

For multiple select you could do something like this

```
<%= f.select(:channel_category, [['Sports', 'sports'],
                                 ['Entertainment', 'entertainment'],
                                 ['Music', 'music']
                                ],{ :prompt => "Please select"},
                                { :multiple => true, :size => 3 }) %>
```

Edit:

then for channels you'll also need multiple select

```
<%= f.select(:channels, [['Channel1', 'ch1'],
                                 ['Channel1', 'ch2'],
                                 ['Channel1', 'ch3']
                                ],{ :prompt => "Please select"},
                                { :multiple => true, :size => 3 }) %>
```

And if you need channels after selecting channel_categories maybe you could try with [conditional validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation).

I had similar problem so I solved it with conditional validations.

Comment: I do not get you why I need nested form.

Comment: I am creating a new Plan in which I can select multiple channel categories as Sports, Entertainment, Music etc. and whichever are selected on that basis I want to select multiple channels based on above selected channel categories.

Comment: Can you please guide me as it is working for single channel category.

Comment: But I want to get channels for multiple channel categories. Hope now you get my requirement.

Comment: This is I have done but on selecting channel category I want channels of that channel category to be come in another drop-down and I can select multiple channels in that second drop-down.

Comment: Yes I need channels using AJAX or JQuery on the basis of channel categories. Can you provide me that piece of code.